# Modify a shape and have modifications apply to clones

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there any any "Symmetry Modifier" option in illustrator?

Let's say I want to create a head that is totally symmetric. I created one half then mirrored it to get another half. Flipped the other half, aligned them and joined them together with **Pathfinder→Unite** option.

Now I modified some portion of the right half outline. But how can I get that same modification to be updated on the left option? I thought it would happen automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a perfectly symmetrical flat onion dome?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115048/how-to-create-a-perfectly-symmetrical-flat-onion-dome)

Comment: @Danielillo I don't think that this is a dupe at all, they specifically described a process which works exactly like Symbols. (Make a shape and then have changes applied to copies)

Comment: @Danielillo my question is not related to your link. Please check. I mentioned after creating an object if I want to modify it so that the modification is applicable to all the sketch.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using Symbols, instead of editing the actual object, you would edit the symbol, that would copy to all of them.

Open the *Symbols Panel* (**Window → Symbols** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)

[image]

Drag you object into the panel, to turn it into a symbol.

Your object is now a symbol, you can clone it and reflect it etc.

In order to make changes, you need to double click it. Changes will be applied to any clones of the symbol once you click out.

[image]

If you need to, once satisfied and done you can Expand the shapes (**Object → Expand**) and only select **Objects** and then merge them together using the *Shapebuilder Tool* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

---

#### [Read more](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/symbols.html) about Symbols at Adobe.

---

Some other GIFs

[image]
[image]

▲ Notice how any change I make (by opening the symbol) is automatically applied to all other versions of the symbol (even if they are rotated, reflected etc.)