# Constructing a basic shield from primary shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder, technical-drawing

I was wondering if it's possible to create these relatively basic shapes from the primary geometric shapes (i.e. polygons and ellipses - particularly circles, squares, and triangles).

You don't necessarily have to use Illustrator, that's just what I use (pathfinder, shape builder, boolean operations, etc.). It's probably more related to geometry and tech drawing with a straight edge & compass than anything.

[image]

These were done relatively freehand and by tracing curves with the pencil & pen/Bézier curve tools. None came out perfectly symmetrical, so I split them down the middle, and paired the best half of each one with its mirror image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a perfectly symmetrical flat onion dome?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115048/how-to-create-a-perfectly-symmetrical-flat-onion-dome)

Answer (score 6):

When you draw two overlaping circles and a line, a simple shield shape (similar to a gothic arc) emerges in the overlap:

[image]

If you move the circles closer to each other, you'll get a narrower shield:

[image]

If you instead move the line upwards, you can extend the circle segments on the sides:

[image]

If you combine three circles, you can get a circle segment at the top:

[image]

And if you throw in a rectangle and some additional circles, you can start building more complex shapes:

[image]

When you have build a geometry you like, you can use *Shape Builder Tool* to combine the shapes like this:

[image]

Comment: Protip: When you made the shield, hit `ctrl+x` to cut the shield then do a  `ctrl+a` and `delete`. Its faster.

Comment: @joojaa, that's right, but it looks strange on a gif .

Answer (score 2):

Creating one half of a shield, and then duplicating and reflecting is probably the simplest way to get a perfectly symmetrical shape.

You could certainly start by using geometric shapes such as the Ellipse tool and Rectangle tool.

Here's an example shown below where I drew some ellipses and a rectangle to create the basic shape (left), then used the Shape Builder tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to create the desired shape (middle), then deleted the other parts by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking on them.

Then I tweaked the Bézier curves using the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd>, then made a copy of the shape and reflected it (left), and moved it into position using Smart Guides to help align everything.

[image]

Finally, the two shapes can then be united using the Shape Builder tool by clicking and dragging it across both shapes.