# Adobe Illustrator: Auto-Mirroring Bézier Handles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, bezier-curve

In the background (black) is an auto-traced outline of a raster image.
In the foreground (red) I'm trying to replicate that kind of helix/hourglass style Bézier curve. How can I get the second handle to automatically mirror the manual adjustments I'm making to the first handle? I've seen it done before, but can't seem to do it myself.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wonder if answers to this related question might be able to help you: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115048/how-to-create-a-perfectly-symmetrical-flat-onion-dome - it's not a duplicate, but the same techniques could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Draw 1/4.. flip horizontal, connect, flip (both) vertical, connect again.

This is quick, loose, and dirty, but ends up slightly *more* symmetrical than the original when flipping one part repeatedly.

[image]

You can also use the **Convert Anchor Tool** on that center node and it will inherently mirror both handles.

There may be third-party plug-ins for this, but there's nothing inherently within Illustrator to mirror handles after they are already established. You sort of have to do it while you are drawing.

Comment: As @Billy Kerr mentions in their comment on the OP question, you can set up a Transform Effect / Reflect X in the appearance palette, and in fact could stack this with another reflect in Y and get a quad from one source object - so you draw it in one quadrant and the other quadrants are created by the Transform Effect - this does require some care in setting up horizontal and vertical transforms to get the right reflections, but I've just tested with the hourglass figure and it works well.

Comment: True, that certainly works. I don't intend to discredit that method. However, I'm prefer things more, well, "tactile" I suppose (for lack of a better term). I'd rather reflect and join than add an effect with the need to expand. Not really an issue either way -- more of a desired workflow than anything.